# What is the easiest way to fetch the entity value in java giving other attributes

Tags: java

What would be the easiest way to fetch the value given from, to as arguments. Should I iterate and find or is there a more elegant way?

```
FOO.java (from, to, value)

public static FOO ONE = new FOO(6000000, 7000000, "60 - 70");
public static FOO TWO = new FOO(7000000, 8000000, "70 - 80");
public static FOO THREE = new FOO(8000000, 9000000, "80 - 90");

private static List<FOO> VALID_FOOS = new ArrayList<FOO>();
VALID_FOOS.add(ONE);
VALID_FOOS.add(TWO);
VALID_FOOS.add(THREE);
```

Comment: If you are searching by from property, in static instances. Then maybe put them in a map? Where the key is the from value. Then you can access the value quickly. But it will require unique values as keys.

Comment: Easiest aka "best" is always relative. Do you want "easy" source code, or do you have millions of objects, and you need a high performance solution?

Comment: performant solution

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you're not by any chance doing some trading system or so with thousands of requests per second, maps ans streams will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays one would use streams, I'd say (though this would be more suitable if `from` and `to` define a range and you search by a single value within the range):

```
List<String> wanted = VALID_FOOS.stream()
.filter(foo -> foo.from == from & foo.to == to)
.map(foo -> foo.value)
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If you want to use the map-approach you'd need to have a structure somewhat on that line (you can find more on Tuples [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/java-misc/java-tuples/)):

```
public class FOO {
    public final Tuple<Integer, Integer> range;
    public final String value;
}

Map<FOO, String> VALID_FOOS ...
```

and retrieve your wanted foo by

```
VALID_FOOS.get(new Tuple(from, to));
```